# How to add prefix to files' names, replace a character, and move to new directory?

Tags: python, replace, rename

For example, the files will look like `FG-4.jpg`  `FG-5.jpg`, etc. and need to be copied to a new directory and named `test_FG_4.jpg` `test_FG_5.jpg`, etc.

Here is the updated code:

```
import shutil
import glob
import os
InFolder = r"C:\test_in"
OutFolder = r"C:\test_out"

for f in glob.glob('*'):
    shutil.move(InFolder/*, OutFolder, copy_function=copy2)
    os.listdir(OutFolder)
    new_filename = f.replace("-","_")
    new_filename = "test_" + new_filename
    os.rename(f,new_filename)
```

I'm getting the error

```
File "c:\copyRename2.py", line 8, in ?
  shutil.move(InFolder/*, OutFolder, copy_function=copy2)

invalid syntax: copyRename2.py, line 8, pos 26 in file c:\copyRename2.py, line 8
shutil.move(InFolder/*, OutFolder, copy_function=copy2)
```

First attempt:

```
import shutil
import glob
import os
InFolder = r"C:\test_in"
OutFolder = r"C:\test_out"

for f in glob.glob('*'):
    shutil.copyfile(f, OutFolder)
    new_filename = f.replace("-","_")
    new_filename = "test_" + new_filename
    os.rename(f,new_filename)
```

Comment: Here's a tip: when you rename the file, you can also move it; because you can rename the file and its entire path at the same time.

Comment: use [shutil.move(InFolder/*, OutFolder, copy_function=copy2)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to copy your files to OutFolder.
Then use [os.listdir(OutFolderPath)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). It will give you list of files in your InFolder directory `[file1, file2]` and then you can change each filename using `os.rename(filename, 'test_'+filename)`

Comment: I updated the original post to reflect the changes you suggested but I don't think I implemented them correctly. The new error is also updated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you want. So this program checks for any file with extension .jpg and then copies them into a new folder("NewDir") by adding "Test_" to the file name. If the folder doesn't exist, the program creates the folder. Maybe you can make the changes you need based on this program.

```
import shutil
import os
newdir="NewDir"
for m in (os.listdir()):
    if m[-4:]==(".txt"):

        if os.path.isdir(newdir):
            shutil.copy(m,newdir+"/"+"Test_"+m)
        else:
            os.mkdir(newdir)
            shutil.copy(m,newdir+"/"+"Test_"+m)
```